# java RMI newbie-- how to ensure that all server-code other than that accessed via RMI, is not accessibly by client

Tags: java, rmi

I am creating an RMI Service, and I Would like to ensure that only the portion of code that is accessed via the RMI service, can be accessed by a client machine....i.e. all server side code which is part of the RMI server app, and is not accessible via RMI, should not be accessible by a user who has access only to the client machine.

How do I ensure the above? Am I correct in thinking that this can be done by appropriate policies in the RMI Policy file? What are the policies required for implementing the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No server code that isn't exported via a remote interface is accessible by the client. Even serialized objects passed to the client as a result of a remote method invocation execute at the client, not the server, so they can't compromise the server in any way. This is basically not a real question.

Comment: @EJP-- ok suppose i have 2 classes com.class1 and com.class2-- and com.class1 is accessed by client machine via RMI-- class2 is a server side class(used by server app and not used by the RMI service directly or indirectly)-- is the code of class2 also accessible by client? thanks....

Comment: @Arvind I've just answered that in my first sentence.

Comment: thanks... this is the first time i m using RMI hence pardon me if my question seems silly to you :)  Thanks anyway...